# How to set and get values in Detail Properties of file? c#

Tags: c#, file-properties

I recently tried the `Shell32.dll` , which allowed me to get the values, but doesn't allow me to set them.

Tried `DSOFile.dll`, it does allow me to read a very few values, but doesn't allow me to set them.

Anyway i can do this?

Answer (score 2):

Try below link this will help you to solve your problem:-

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7987/Retrieve-detailed-information-of-a-File

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/bb887b05-2018-4978-b115-c8c98e3542ce

Comment: First link only reads, its ok...
Seconds link reads and can write on some attributes, not all...

Comment: there are possibility that you have readonly attribute.Do you want to change them as well.

Comment: I mean, second link has functionality to write on some attributes, fo others I can do nothing... can't access them...

Comment: This answer is old, but, please, add the important / most  relevant information in the answer itself. Links rot (especially the ones from microsoft), making the answer not useful anymore to the visitors of Stack Overflow.